# Shortest and longest city name and alphabetical order

Tags: sql, mysql

> **Problem**
>
> Query the two cities in STATION with the shortest and longest CITY
>   names, as well as their respective lengths (i.e.: number of characters
>   in the name). If there is more than one smallest or largest city,
>   choose the one that comes first when ordered alphabetically.
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> Let's say that CITY only has four entries: DEF, ABC, PQRS and WXY
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> ABC 3 
> PQRS 4

Can I get shorter code in MySQL and also an optimal Oracle query? There's no way to have only one sub-query for both min and max, is there?

```
select city, char_length(city) from STATION 
 where city = (select min(city) from STATION
     where char_length(city) = (select min(char_length(city)) from STATION)) 

 or city = (select min(city) from STATION
     where char_length(city) = (select max(char_length(city)) from STATION));
```

Comment: I'm not up for writing a review, but you should look into `TOP`/`LIMIT` and use `ORDER BY` to make the query more clear

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are requesting "also an optimal Oracle query"? Oracle is a completely separate database management system (arguably a better one) than MySQL.

Comment: `SELECT city, char_length(city) FROM station ORDER BY char_length(city) DESC, city LIMIT 1` might do the trick (but test). If you're golfing, `ORDER BY 2 DESC, 1` might work for the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: @Phrancis I have learnt Oracle only. Just for this problem, I did a MySQL query - but it's not what I generally use. That is why I'm looking for an Oracle implementation.

Comment: @BarryCarter What does `ORDER BY 2` mean?

Comment: @ProgramSpree It means order by the second column in the SELECT clause. In this case, that's `char_length(city)`. In this case I did `2 DESC` since I want longest cities first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Formatting

Your SQL statement formatting is not very good. I would encourage you to use a free tool like [sql-format.com](http://www.sql-format.com/) (or one of the many others) to format your SQL queries in a more readable way. This is your original query, with better formatting (I indented the subqueries by hand because the tool didn't).

```
SELECT
    city,
    CHAR_LENGTH(city)
FROM STATION
WHERE city = (
    SELECT
        MIN(city)
    FROM STATION
    WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(city) = (
        SELECT
            MIN(CHAR_LENGTH(city))
        FROM STATION
    )
)
OR city = (
    SELECT
        MIN(city)
    FROM STATION
    WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(city) = (
        SELECT
            MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(city))
        FROM STATION
    )
);
```

Now we can see much more easily how deeply nested queries are.

---

### Variables

You could make the code simpler by using a few [user-defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html):

```
SET @MinCityLen = (SELECT MIN(CHAR_LENGTH(city)) FROM STATION);
SET @MaxCityLen = (SELECT MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(city)) FROM STATION);
/* Query below only to demonstrate the variables */
SELECT 
  '@MinCityLen' AS `VariableName`, 
  @MinCityLen AS `Value`
UNION
SELECT 
  '@MaxCityLen', 
  @MaxCityLen;
```

Which returns this:

> ```
> VariableName  Value
> @MinCityLen   3
> @MaxCityLen   4
> ```

This will abstract away one level of nesting and make the query simpler to understand. Note that the `@` symbol is just a convention, it is not needed as far as MySQL syntax goes. Some database systems do require the `@` symbol though, the most famous being Microsoft SQL Server.

---

### Shorter code != Better code

Sometimes, better code is longer rather than shorter. This is often the case with SQL. Longer code can be better formatted, better documented, better abstracted, better structured. In my personal SQL experience, short queries, unless they are very simple, are often pretty bad. Yours is not a case of a very simple query.

This is what I came up with. I also have a link on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/573f09/40/1)

```
# find shortest city name
SET @MinCityLen = (SELECT MIN(CHAR_LENGTH(city)) FROM STATION);
# find longest city name
SET @MaxCityLen = (SELECT MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(city)) FROM STATION);

SELECT
    city,
    CHAR_LENGTH(city)
FROM 
    STATION
WHERE 
    # find shortest city name sorted alphabetically
    city = (
        SELECT
            city
        FROM STATION
        WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(city) = @MinCityLen
        ORDER BY city ASC
        LIMIT 1
    )
    # find longest city name sorted alphabetically
    OR city = (
        SELECT
            MIN(city)
        FROM STATION
        WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(city) = @MaxCityLen
        ORDER BY city ASC
        LIMIT 1
    );
```

Comment: Thank you for your formatting help! The shorter MySQL code returns "@MinCityLen", but I want the city name to be displayed. Also, thank you for the last documented code. Is there any way to merge both max and min finding queries into one?

Answer (score 5):

It took me a while to think about the answer and how to present it in a presentable manner. The following works just fine:

```
SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) FROM STATION ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY), CITY ASC LIMIT 1;
SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) FROM STATION ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: You have presented a good alternative solution (exactly how I would approach the problem), but you haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] it to explain your reasoning (how your solution works and why that is an improvement upon the original) so that everyone can learn from your thought process.

Comment: OP needs a single query to get both min and max cities.

Answer (score 1):

I think, presentation matters. My solution shows each parts separately in a human readable manner. The steps show how to break the problem before we begin to solve it

**Idea** : Find all cities that have the smallest length.

**STEPS:**

- Find the minimum length of city .
- Get all cities that have the MIN Length.
- Sort by CITY .
- Output the first result only.

**Repeat same for MAX**

```
select CITY, length(CITY) from STATION where length(CITY) = (
    select MIN(length(CITY)) from STATION 
    ) order by CITY limit 1;

select CITY, length(CITY) from STATION where length(CITY) = (
    select MAX(length(CITY)) from STATION 
    ) order by CITY limit 1;
```

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] it to explain your reasoning (how your solution works and how it improves upon the original) so that everyone can learn from your thought process.